# CSS trick for maximum inline image indentation

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I'm having trouble finding a solution to my problem on the Web. 
My problem is this :
Say I have three elements:
div#container with a varying width. 
The container contains two elements - div#text with an unknown width and div#img with a fixed width. Both elements are inline:

```html
<div id="container" style="width:auto">
    <div id="text"> some varying text here... </div>
    <div id="img" style="width: 10px; background: url(img.png)">
</div>
```

Where the styling for the text is somewhere along:

```css
#text { width:auto; max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

I want the location of the image to be close to the text, but at most at the rightmost border of the container, as illustrated by the image [here](http://i41.tinypic.com/2a94bqt.png)

Is there a way to achieve this *without using javascript*? Though the container is appended to the document dynamically, and so width calculations cannot be used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm kind of confused, but are you referring to floating?

Comment: some codes of yours you've tried, might help us to help you ...

Comment: ..or better yet, a picture.

Comment: Updated my question with code sample and a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Took me a lot of time, and brought me to the darkest corners of CSS.
And yet, I've emerged enlightened - and the answer is so simple....

```
<div id="container" style="width:auto">
    <div id="text"> some varying text here... </div>
    <div id="img" style="width: 10px; background: url(img.png)">
</div>
```

And The CSS:

```
#text { 
    width:auto; 
    max-width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 

    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

As shown [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZSlaver/JftJN/)

Answer (score 0):

This was as close as I got to your requisitions:

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLHvW/2/)</kbd>

Unfortunately, due to the behaviour of `text-overflow: ellipsis`, it's really hard to get the desired behaviour without setting a max-width. And then, the image won't be next to a shorter text-block. An option would be `text-align: right` as you see in my example.

It would be far more easier to just place the text on the right side:
<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLHvW/4/)</kbd>

Comment: That's not what I'm aiming for, but that's close. That's my problem exactly - I would've calculated the width beforehand, if I wasn't building an HTML control that can be used dynamically, and styled with CSS.

Comment: Well, I ran out of good ideas. Good luck! And don't forget to post a solution, if you got one. Maybe it's helping others!

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! I'm absolutely sure I can use this someday! Thanks for sharing :)
I pimped up your example a little bit and stripped it down to the bare minimum, enjoy: [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JftJN/4/)